# Return specific HTTP status code in action for GET request

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-web-api

I'm creating REST service using ASP.NET Web API.
How can I return 401 status code from action for GET method...

I don't have problem with returning some status code from e.g. POST method, cause I can set the return type to HttpResponseMessage

```
   public HttpResponseMessage Post(Car car)
    {
        using (var context = new CarEntities())
        {
            ...
            var response = new HttpResponseMessage(HttpStatusCode.Created);
            response.Headers.Location = new Uri(Request.RequestUri, path);
            return response;
        }
    }
```

However, how can I return the status code for GET method, when the method returns different type than HttpResponseMessage:

```
public Car Get(int id)
{

    var context = new CarEntities();
    return context.Cars.Where(p => p.id == id).FirstOrDefault();
}
```

I would like to return e.g. 401 when authorization in this Get method failed

Thanks

Comment: I don't see any authentication going on in the action.  Where would this authentication occur?  If you going to need to do this in multiple actions I would look into perhaps using an Authentication attribute and decorate the actions as required?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You should throw a [`HttpResponseException`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.http.httpresponseexception%28v=vs.108%29.aspx), which allows you to specify the response code, for example:

```
if (authFailed) {
    throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);
}
```