# Wrong HTTP Response Code from ASP.NET Web API

Tags: asp.net-web-api

I'm trying to return a 401 (unauthorized) response code from ASP.NET Web API web method (POST) but I get a 404.  Am I doing something wrong?

`throw new HttpResponseException(HttpStatusCode.Unauthorized);` (or setting it on the HttpResponseMessage)

Thanks

Comment: This question 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9852493/return-specific-http-status-code-in-action-for-get-request
shows the same method but it is wrapped in an if statement checking if the auth failed.
 Do you have any code in front of the exception that might be causing a valid 404 Error ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Grrr - the problem was forms authentication, which hijacks the 401 and issues a redirect (302) to a non-existant login form, hence the 404. I just had to set the authentication mode to none in the web.config file.

Comment: Hi, any idea how you do this if the WebApi is hosted in a FormsAuth MVC project?